# Slick Carousel not functioning correctly with WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I have been using Slick Carousel for a little while now, doing basic sliders. However, I have run into a problem which I cannot figure out!

When I try to load the required files, slick does not work. First I loaded the required files as stated in the Slick's [Get Started](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started) guide and that worked fine. However, when I go to implement it using the `functions.php` file in WordPress, things doesn't work properly.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that loading the following files this way makes it work, but when I add them to the `functions.php` file, it stops working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

My `functions.php` file is as follows:

```
function files() {
    // Stylesheets
    wp_enqueue_style('main_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime());
    wp_enqueue_style('slick_stylesheet', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick.css'), array(), NULL, false);
    wp_enqueue_style('slick_theme', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick-theme.css'), array('slick_stylesheet'), NULL, false);
    // Javascript
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick_script', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('slick_init', get_theme_file_uri('/js/slick-init.js'), array('slick_script'), NULL, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'files');
```

The slick slider has been initialised in a separate file: `slick-init.js`.

Does anyone know why this isn't working when I load the two jQuery script files from the `functions.php` file, but works when I load them just above the `</body>` tag manually?

Comment: Did you check your browser console? Did you see any error? A link to the website will be good to troubleshoot such problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Kashif Rafique. No errors were in the console which baffled me. Unfortunately the site isn't live yet so you can have looked yourself. However, I managed to figure it out. View my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more time playing with the code, I finally found the solution, and it's a pretty annoying but a simple one.

One of the `wp_enqueue_script()` parameters asks for dependencies as stated [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). After troubleshooting for some time I figured JQuery wasn't being loaded at the right time. So as shown in the question I over writ JQuery, and the parameter which looks at the dependencies was set to an empty array (`array('')`). I changed this to `NULL` as I was running out of ideas, and surprisingly it worked!

So the fixed line of code looks like this:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', NULL, '1.11.0', false);
```